# How can I put advertisements on my WiFi hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking

i was wondering How  I can put advertisements on my WiFi hotspot, whenever someone connects on my hotspot a message pops up on his devise advertising my products

Answer (score 1):

Set up a web server/website with ads for your product on your network, and configure your Wi-Fi APs to use that website as their "captive portal". If your APs don't support captive portal, you'll either have to load aftermarket firmware like OpenWrt on them, or buy different APs that support it.

Once you set that up, when anyone joins your network and tries to go to an unencrypted website, they'll see your ads website instead.